# Erro messageContext.add

Tags: demoiselle

Conforme o [manual](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/quickstart/2.5.0-RC1/html_single/#d0e692) descreve para inserir uma mensagem usamos o seguinte comando

```
messageContext.add(InfoMessages.BOOKMARK_INSERT_OK, bookmark.getDescription());
```

Só que o metodo add deve receber apenas uma "String message e Object... params" isso gera um erro pois estamos passando um tipo Message como seria o correto proceder ? 
Devo informar assim:

```
messageContext.add(InfoMessages.BOOKMARK_INSERT_OK.getText(),
  bookmark.getDescription());
```

e também:

```
messageContext.add(InfoMessages.BOOKMARK_INSERT_OK.getText(),    
  InfoMessages.BOOKMARK_INSERT_OK.getSeverity(), bookmark.getDescription());
```

Não deveria exitir um método que recebesse o objeto Message ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gustavo, se você der uma olhadinha [aqui](http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/framework/reference/2.5.0-RC1/html/mensagem.html#d0e1974) na documentação de referência vai ver que é sim possível passar um objeto `Message` para o método `add` do `MessageContext`. Existe a seguinte interface para esse método: `void add(Message message, Object... params)`, assim ele pode receber 0 ou mais parâmetros, além da mensagem.

Comment: Então Emerson a documentação diz que sim, mas usando o archetype demoiselle-jsf-parent versão 2.5.0 a interface br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.message.MessageContext não tem o método que recebe o objeto Message. Já fiz o update do projeto maven achando que fosse esse o problema e persiste o problema.
Verifiquei a versão 2.4.2 e esse método existe contanto está anotado com @Deprecated

Comment: Gustavo, na versão 2.5 parece ter ocorrido realmente um problema. O método estava depreciado, e deveria ter sido substituído pelo método 'void add(Message message)', como indica essa issue (https://demoiselle.atlassian.net/browse/FWK-160). Porém ele foi removido, e não houve a adição do método substituto. Além disso, a documentação dessa versão também está desatualizada quanto a isso. Sugiro que abra duas issues no tracker (https://demoiselle.atlassian.net/projects/FWK/issues/FWK-228?filter=allopenissues) do projeto, relatando a falta do método, e a desatualização da documentação.